# Character Enconding in my java classes in Eclipse is messed up. How to fix it?

Tags: java, eclipse, character-encoding

I got a eclipse project that was working OK.

One day I had to format my machine, so I copied my workspace into a backup, after installing eclipse again, I imported my projects from my backed up workspace.

What happened is that it corrupted all the string that contains special characters..

like.. `é`, `são`, etc.. to `Ã‰`, `sÃ£o`...

Is there a way to refactor it back to normal?

I tried changing character encoding in eclipse, but it doesn't update the class files.

Comment: Why are you looking at the class files?  You may need to rebuild the project.

Answer (score 7):

You need to reconfigure the workspace encoding. Go to *Window* > *Preferences* and enter filter text "encoding" and set to **UTF-8** everywhere when applicable, especially the *Workspace*'s text encoding.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to refactor it back to normal?

Did you try closing an individual file, right-clicking it to open properties and setting its encoding manually?

> like.. é, são, etc.. to Ã‰, sÃ£o...

Are you sure it wasn't **É** (U+00C9) that was becoming **Ã‰** (U+00C3 U+2030)?

That would suggest that files that were being interpreted as UTF-8 before are now being interpreted as something else (probably windows-1252).

---

Many Java compilation problems can be fixed by sticking to the subset of values that appear in the US-ASCII character encoding and using Unicode escape sequences for everything else (this assumes you aren't using UTF-16 or UTF-32 or something).

The code `String foo = "É";` would become `String foo = "\u00C9";`. This improves source code portability at the expense of readability.

You can use the JDK [native2ascii](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/index.html#intl) tool to perform the conversion:

```
native2ascii -encoding UTF-8 Foo.java
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a stupid suggestion, but I figured I'd mention it anyways. Are you opening your `file.class` or your `file.java`? Because the `*.class` files, if I recall correctly, are binary files which explains why you're seeing those weird characters. The `*.java` files are the plain-text source files.

I figure you knew that, but the wording made me feel otherwise, so I figure I'd mention it.

Answer (score 0):

How do the actual .java files on disk look?  Are they damaged, or is it just that eclipse can't display them properly?  If the files look good on disk, setting the encoding property as jjnguy suggest should do the trick.

If the files are damaged on disk, maybe `iconv` can "undamage" them?

To avoid such problem in the future, I actually suggest keeping the java files in plain ASCII, using \uNNNN escapes for non-ascii characters in strings etc (e.g. \u00E4 is ä / ä / &auml; / an a with two dots above).

Comment: irrelevant. it's just that the encoding isn't set properly.

Comment: Do you know that, Bozho?  I know for a fact that eclipse can mess upp files on disk, and I don't see anything in the OP that ascertains that it is just the display that's broken.

Comment: +1 I just had eclipse DAMAGE a bunch of java files. It happens when you take an Eclipse java file saved with an Encoding (in my case it was MacRoman), open it in another environment (Windows, with cp-1252), and save the file again without noticing it was garbled. Now its worse than garbled, now it has parts of each encoding, maybe iconv can try to undamage them? Its ridiculous that Eclipse won't use UTF-8 as the default, being a cross-platform IDE!